# Why this program showing segmentation fault?

Tags: c, pointers

Instead of pointer `char *s` if I use array `char s[100]` (in line 4) the code gets executed. Why is that?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int l=0;
    char *s;
    printf("enter string : \n");
    fgets(s,100,stdin);
    puts(s);
    while(s[l]!='\0'){
        l++;
    }
    printf("length : %d",l-1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't allocate memory for `s`.

Comment: Because s is an uninizialized pointer. You must allocate memory for string: s=malloc(someSize);

Answer (score 2):

Because you haven't allocated any memory for `s`, nor even initialized it to a known value.

That means `fgets()` is scribbling onto some random address, and your program crashes.

With a local `char s[100];` you allocate 100 bytes on the stack, and the value of `s` is a pointer to the zeroth byte of that allocation.